# How do i convert my Python script (that has imported modules) to a windows exe?

Tags: python, py2exe, cx-freeze

Here are the import modules that my script uses :

```
import datetime
from dateutil import parser
from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter
import mailbox
import pprint
import json
import urllib.request
from tkinter import *

#my script code here
```

How can i convert it into a windows exe. Im using python 3.4. People have suggested cx_freeze however there is no documentation on it therefore have no idea how to use it? Py2exe worked on a test script with no imported modules, but when i tried to compile my script, it didnt work?  If my script is called test.py, what would the cx_freeze command be to covnert it?

Comment: have a read of this: http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [www.py2exe.org/](http://www.py2exe.org/)

py2exe is a nice module that you may find useful.
Or, if you are in linux/mac then you might try `freeze` method try https://wiki.python.org/moin/Freeze

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest **PyInstaller**.
I used to use it in order to create the exe file with multiple library files, then compress all these files into a self extracting archive, obtaining a fully working standalone exe file.

It doesn't require other scripts or code, you only have to create the file using "Makespec.py" and "Build.py".

If I'm not wrong, there is a new version compatible with Python 3.4...otherwise you could convert your script to Python 2.7.